# Use Chef recipe to make sure node has certain version of apache

Tags: apache, chef-infra

I've been messing with Chef lately in order to evaluate it and learn it for use as a deployment and infrastructure option. One thing that kind of has me stuck is mainly with Apache.

The version of Apache that comes with the Ubuntu VM I'm running this node on is 2.2.22. I want to make sure that whenever my node converges (using chef-client), it upgrades to 2.4 (if it's not already at that version). The recipes/cookbooks that I've been using use the apt package manager. I know I can manually upgrade Apache using apt, but I figured there has to be a way to tell my main cookbook to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this link for apt_package http://docs.opscode.com/resource_apt_package.html

you can specify

> default[:apache][:version] = '2.4'

in your attributes/default.rb.

Then in the recipe,

```
apt_package "name_of_package" do
  version node[:apache][:version]
end
```

Comment: "name_of_package", should that be 'apache2', or something else? I tried running it with 'apache2' and got the following message: "Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[apache2]; Chef::Exceptions::Exec; apt-get -q -y install apache2=2.4 returned 100, expected 0"

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to add the `action :upgrade` param to the recipe snippet you added. It didn't actually perform the upgrade though, because when I use the `apache2 -v` command it still says 2.2.22